# Inversion should happen only once or multiple times in a single sentence?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-inversion

In a longer, complicated sentence where one repeats the subject, verb and object, does one invert only the first svo or all of them to create a question?
Or maybe both cases are correct with a slightly different meaning?

The example which motivates my question is:

"Could You estimate, very roughly, **when You could send** the samples?"

"Could You estimate, very roughly, **when could You send** the samples?"

My boss insists to use the first form, but he is French native speaker... so let's say that I don't trust his English instincts too much ;)

Comment: Il a raison. Look at the simplified '_Estimate when you could send the samples_, please ... you don't have to be spot on.' Or switch to *'Can you be sure when will you be free?' (the asterisk labels as ungrammatical)

Comment: You boss is right -- the first one is correct. Unlike main clause interrogatives, subordinate interrogatives (embedded questions) don't normally exhibit subject-auxiliary inversion. Compare the main clause interrogative "When could you send the samples?", which does have inversion.